# Ampersand in XML data not allowing to load xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml

i am using a web service which is retrieving me xml, which contains lots of url. i am using below code to load it:

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(fileName.Trim());
```

its not able to load my xml if any ampersand exists in any element's content.
my xml is like:

```
<media:thumbnail url="http://someurl/player/mezzanine/image.php?w=124&h=99&path=ndtv/a79d98c3030c041e0033105943c1b668_mezzn.jpg&hash=23991c2513a8e359d120840e6f897d4d" width="124" height="70" />
<media:fullimage url="" width="350" height="196" />
```

NOTE: i can't do changes in web service, as i am getting this from other provider.
please help me.
Thanks

i am getting this exception:

> System.Xml.XmlException: '=' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'. Line 753, position 89.

on this row

```
<media:thumbnail url="http://someurl/player/mezzanine/image.php?w=124&h=99&path=ndtv/a79d98c3030c041e0033105943c1b668_mezzn.jpg&hash=23991c2513a8e359d120840e6f897d4d" width="124" height="70" />
```

Comment: Well, that is an `invalid XML`, what else do you expect? Character must be **escaped**.

Comment: <rant>Stupid stupid provider. Would anyone ship a library that doesn't even compile? I doubt it. Yet few seem to care about delivering correct markup at all...</rant>

Comment: are you getting an exception? Is yes, then post the stack trace and the source of the exception.

Comment: The reason it can't load your XML is that your XML isn't XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't get the provider to fix their "XML", then the easiest thing to do is run it through a utility, such as [Tidy .NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tidynet/), which attempt to compensate for those sorts of issues and return a well-formed XML file that you can process.

Comment: I disagree. If you can't get the provider to fix their "XML", then to hell with them. This is XML 101 here. This file can't even be loaded in an XML editor. Just don't enable these idiots by doing business with them.

Comment: @john: i am completely agree with you.

Comment: @John Saunders - I agree that it is much better to report the problem and get the producer to fix their broken "XML". . However,  you do not always have he power, influence, or luxury of time, and it is not always possible to force the change. Sometimes you have to use service mediation strategies/tools in order to format the data properly to achieve the desired result. It is not ideal, but is a pragmatic solution that can always be adjusted if/when they fix their broken syndication feed.

Comment: @Mads: I disagree. This pattern of accommodation will only bring us back to where we were before XML - no standards. I think we have to draw the line, at minimum, at "well-formed XML". If the document can't even be loaded into an XML DOM, then send it back.

Comment: @Mads: I personally try to set the bar a bit higher: well-formed, properly handling XML namespaces, inclusion of a schema that actually validates the documents. The latter can be too much to ask, so that's a negotiation point I'll fall back from in order to get the former two.

Comment: @John Saunders, in an ideal world yes. However if the boss says "You use this provider and it has to be done by tomorrow", then it's a straight choice between principles and having a job. In this instance, having a job would win. For me, anyway.

Comment: @Rob: I can't advise you to quit your job. I can only advise you to inform your employer that any provider that can't even produce well-formed XML is likely to screw up in other ways that will your employer money. And I _can_ advise you to start looking for a better job, working for people with some backbone.

Answer (score 3):

Replace each `&` in `url` with `&amp;`

Comment: @abatischev: i am directrly passing url of xml in xml.load and getting the error while loading so how can i perform replace?

Comment: @Rajesh Rolen- DotNet Developer, you could read the xml as a string (`TextReader`). Perform string.Replace() and then call xmlDoc.LoadXml(string).

Answer (score 2):

Replacing `&` with `&amp;` fixes this for me for the IE client-side XML parser which I assume is the same library.  Interestingly, FF didn't have issues with the & character between double-quotes.